# Reference to another row in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say I have the following table in Excel:
[image]

I want to be able to select a task and a date from a user form I created so the matching cell will be colored. 
I'm using a For loop on the tasks columns to find and go to the required task but I can't find out how to loop over each row and find the matching date from above for each cell.

Any help would be appreciated
thank you.

Comment: there shouldn't be any need to loop-you can use two application.match statements to find the row and column positions and then just color that cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sub` below will do that for you (essentially implementing @JosieP's comment):

```
Sub ColorCell(strTask As String, datDate As Date)
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    With WorksheetFunction
        lRow = .Match(strTask, Range("C4:C10"), 0)
        lCol = .Match(CLng(datDate), Range("D2:N2"), 0)
    End With

    Sheet1.Range("C2").Offset(1 + lRow, lCol).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    MsgBox "Date or Task out of range. Try again", vbOKOnly
End Sub
```